# Twitter Bio intersection character - how to insert?

Tags: twitter, special-characters

I have a tagline I use on my webpage and email signature: People Plants Place with the intersection symbol &#8745 between first two strings:

[image]

I'd like to use this in my Twitter bio but no success so far.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Did you try to copy and paste the same in bio (not image, just text)?

Comment: Thanks heaps it works perfectly see -  https://twitter.com/GrowplanLtd_NZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy and paste the text (not image) in the bio section.